# Alert dialog bug in Xcode 11.1?

Tags: swift, xcode11

I decided to update Xcode to Version 11.1 (11A1027) yesterday and I think I either found a bug or the Swift Syntax changed.

I have an almost blank viewController that has two buttons, one dismisses the ViewController and the other displays an alert.

```
@IBAction func search_BTN(_ sender: Any) {
    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.text = "Some default text"
    }

    // 3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
        print("Text field: \(textField?.text)")
    }))

    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The alert will **ONLY** display if I remove the `addTextField` code. Else the app freezes up and I have to force close it. What I think is happening is either a blank dialog is being displayed or the program is getting stuck in a loop. The reason I think this is, because the app doesn't crash and I get no error messages. The only thing I get is this,

`XPC connection interrupted`

Which to the best of my knowledge means the App timed out.

What I've tried

- Other view controllers (Got the same problem)
- Another Xcode project (Got the same problem)
- Xcode 10 (That worked)
- Cleaning the project

What I haven't tired

- A physical iOS device (Just simulator)
- Another computer using latest version of Xcode

Can anyone confirm this bug? Does anyone know a workaround to this problem? Or is there another way of displaying an alert with a textfield without installing Pods (I like using as much 1st party code as possible).

**EDIT1**: I think this may be just Textfields in general. I tired getting around the problem by just using a textfield in the view controller but I'm still getting the same issue. I also tired cleaning the project and rebuilding. Same thing happened. Will probably uninstall and reinstall Xcode. If that doesn't work I might have to try to install a beta version.

**EDIT2**: I had a crazy idea to do something that makes complete sense. I updated my OS to Catalina and that fixed the problem. If someone knows why this happened I would be interested in finding out. Assuming this has to do with caching of some sorts.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue with Xcode 11.1. Please show enough information (other parts of your code or settings?). Or you may not have shown your code exactly.

Comment: I updated my os and that fixed the problem. Makes sense to me...not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently and apparently it’s a bug confirmed by Apple: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122972

There is a workaround that consists on disabling the pasteboard sync on the simulator.

Uncheck the option in Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard

Restart the simulator.

Comment: Actually had this issue again and had to come back here for a reference. Thanks